# Flutter Listener does not work with Container margin

Tags: flutter, dart, stack, listener, margin

I want to code a Joystick. There should be some lines on the Joystick to show areas on it. Therefore I use the Stack and Positioned Widget to overlay the circled Container and the Lines. With a Listener I want to get the position of the finger. If I have no margin in the circle Container (line 50), the container is obviously in the top left corner and the Listener works. (I can see this because the coordinates are shown in the Textfield. However when I have margin in the container (line 50), the coordinates are to changing if i put my finger on the display. I need the margin to position the container exactly, to calculate later in which area my finger is. Does anyone know why the coordinates are not updating with margin and what I can do?

CODE:

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
    DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
  ]);
  runApp(const MaterialApp(home: MyHomePage()));
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  double x = 0.0;
  double y = 0.0;

  void _updateLocation(PointerEvent details) {
    setState(() {
      x = details.position.dx;
      y = details.position.dy;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double screenheight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    //double screenwidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          /*Container(
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage('assets/backgroundapp.jpg'), scale: 0.5),
            ),
          ),*/
          Listener(
            onPointerMove: _updateLocation,
            child: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                  screenheight * 0.5 - screenheight * 0.44,
                  screenheight * 0.5,
                  0,
                  0),
              height: screenheight * 0.44,
              width: screenheight * 0.44,
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  color: Color.fromARGB(130, 0, 0, 0), shape: BoxShape.circle),
            ),
          ),
          const LineJoystick(angle: 11.25),
          const LineJoystick(angle: 33.75),
          const LineJoystick(angle: 56.25),
          const LineJoystick(angle: 78.75),
          const LineJoystick(angle: 101.25),
          const LineJoystick(angle: 123.75),
          const LineJoystick(angle: 146.25),
          const LineJoystick(angle: 168.75),
          const LineJoystick(angle: 191.25),
          const LineJoystick(angle: 213.75),
          const LineJoystick(angle: 236.25),
          const LineJoystick(angle: 258.75),
          const LineJoystick(angle: 281.25),
          const LineJoystick(angle: 303.75),
          const LineJoystick(angle: 326.25),
          const LineJoystick(angle: 348.75),
          Text(
            'The cursor is here: (${x.toStringAsFixed(2)}, ${y.toStringAsFixed(2)})',
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class LinePainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paint = Paint()
      ..color = const Color.fromARGB(100, 255, 255, 255)
      ..strokeWidth = 1;

    canvas.drawLine(
      Offset(size.width * 0.67, size.height * 0.5),
      Offset(size.width * 0.87, size.height * 0.5),
      paint,
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}

class LineJoystick extends StatefulWidget {
  const LineJoystick({required this.angle, super.key});
  final double angle;

  @override
  State<LineJoystick> createState() => _LineJoystickState();
}

class _LineJoystickState extends State<LineJoystick> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double screenheight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Positioned(
      top: screenheight * 0.5,
      left: screenheight * 0.5 - screenheight * 0.44,
      child: Transform.rotate(
        angle: widget.angle * math.pi / 180 * -1,
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.transparent,
          height: screenheight * 0.44,
          width: screenheight * 0.44,
          child: CustomPaint(
            foregroundPainter: LinePainter(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you
Max

Comment: Are you referring tap event doesnt work  ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the code, `Listener` is dependent on `Container` and it lays at the **bottom of the stack** and it has other Containers on top, which makes `Listener` not accessible. Here I tried another way.

**First**, replace your current body with:

```
body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text(
            'The cursor is here: (${x.toStringAsFixed(2)}, ${y.toStringAsFixed(2)})',
          ),
          Listener(
            onPointerMove: _updateLocation,
            child: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                left: screenheight * 0.5 - screenheight * 0.44,
                top: screenheight * 0.5,
              ),
              height: screenheight * 0.44,
              width: screenheight * 0.44,
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  color: Color.fromARGB(130, 0, 0, 0), shape: BoxShape.circle),
              child: Stack(
                children: const <Widget>[
                  LineJoystick(angle: 11.25),
                  LineJoystick(angle: 33.75),
                  LineJoystick(angle: 56.25),
                  LineJoystick(angle: 78.75),
                  LineJoystick(angle: 101.25),
                  LineJoystick(angle: 123.75),
                  LineJoystick(angle: 146.25),
                  LineJoystick(angle: 168.75),
                  LineJoystick(angle: 191.25),
                  LineJoystick(angle: 213.75),
                  LineJoystick(angle: 236.25),
                  LineJoystick(angle: 258.75),
                  LineJoystick(angle: 281.25),
                  LineJoystick(angle: 303.75),
                  LineJoystick(angle: 326.25),
                  LineJoystick(angle: 348.75),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

And remove `Positioned` widget from `LineJoystick`'s build method. It will be just:

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double screenheight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    /// No need Positioned widget anymore
    return Transform.rotate(
      angle: widget.angle * math.pi / 180 * -1,
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.transparent,
        height: screenheight * 0.44,
        width: screenheight * 0.44,
        child: CustomPaint(
          foregroundPainter: LinePainter(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Hope that helps!